# p:selectOneMenu não lista

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou na luta tentando popular um `selectOneMenu` com dados de um `Enum`, mas quando desisti e coloquei os dados estáticos com `f:selectItem` percebi que mesmo assim o campo fica vazio.

Mesmo com o value preenchido com `#{clienteBean.teste}` o resultado é o mesmo, onde teste é um atributo do tipo `String` com seus getters e setters.

```
                <p:selectOneMenu id="console" value="" style="width:125px">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Xbox One" itemValue="Xbox One" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="PS4" itemValue="PS4" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Wii U" itemValue="Wii U" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

obs: o exemplo acima é o mesmo do showcase.

Comment: Você pode postar o código do enum e seu método, se tiver,  que retorna todos os valores do enum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue um exemplo:

No Enum:

```
public enum ClienteTipos{

    SUSPECT("Suspect"),
    PROSPECT("Prospect"),
    CLIENTE("Cliente");

    ClienteTipos(String nome){
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    //Attributes
    private String nome;


    //Properties
    public String getNome(){
       return nome;
    }
}
```

No ManagedBean:

```
public SelectItem[] getTiposCliente() {
    SelectItem[] items = new SelectItem[ClienteTipos.values().length];
    int i = 0;
    for(ClienteTipos t: ClienteTipos.values()) {
        items[i++] = new SelectItem(t, t.getNome());
    }
    return items;
}
```

Na página xhtml (JSF):

```
<h:selectOneListbox id="tipo" size="1" value="#{clienteMB.cliente.tipo}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{clienteMB.tiposCliente}" var="t" 
        itemLabel="#{t.nome}" itemValue="#{t}"/>
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

Fonte: [Enum JSF SelectOneMenu](http://codepianist.com/java-ee/capturar-os-valores-do-enum-no-selectonemenu-jsf2/)

Comment: Funcionou! muito obrigado.